# how can I change class method to instance method in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Now, I am facing the problem of creating an instance method.
Item has multiple images in active storage.

I created a class method something like below.

```
  def self.get_url(item)
      item.images.map do |image|
        Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(image)
      end
  end
```

this class method worked completely fine.
But I want to change this to instance method so that I use this other place without an argument item.

So I want it to be something like this.

```
  def get_url
      item.images.map do |image|
        Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(image)
      end
  end
```

But I can't do this, because nothing like item is defined.

And I want to use it like this.

```
item.get_url
```

If you could help me I would really appreciate it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `def self.get_url(item)`, I'll assume `item` is an instance of the class, so if you want to create an instance method, simply drop the `item` part from `item.images`:

```
def get_url
  images.map do |image|
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(image)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! 
I thought that would work but images is attached to item so I thought I need it to be written. 
has_many_attached :images

Comment: I have just tried it and it worked! thank you.